# how to have set state for sibling component in React without updating

Tags: reactjs, react-state-management, react-state

I have 2 sibling components in 1 parent component. It's like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PlaceSearchInput from './PlaceSearchInput';
import { GoogleMap, withGoogleMap } from "react-google-maps";

export default function Search(props) {
    const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({lat:3, lng:2});

    function Map() {

        return (
            <div>
            <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} center={mapCenter}/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    const WrappedMap = withGoogleMap(Map);

    if (!props.isGoogleMapApiReady)
        return (
            <div>Loading...</div>
        )

    return (
        <div style={{ margin: "100px" }}>
           <div style={{ height: "50vh", width: "50vh" }}>
                <WrappedMap
                    loadingElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
                    containerElement={<div id="map" style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
                    mapElement={<div style={{ height: "100%" }} />}
                />
                <PlaceSearchInput setMapCenter={setMapCenter} />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I want Input sets coordinates and Map shows the coordinates. I know one way is that having coordinates state in parent and then passing set function to Input, coordinates to Map. But with this way I found out it whenever state is changed by Input component, though Map does move to new coordinates, Map is refreshed and that is what I want to avoid. Is there way to solve it?

Comment: Can you say more about how Map will "show coordinates" without re-rendering?

Comment: You can use third-party storage like Redux then it's work. but a good idea is you keep every component independent.

Comment: @JamieDixon Sorry, my explanation was not so clear. I mean when Input sets coordinates state, Map moves to the new coordinates but when it happens, it's like the map is refreshed (like you press F5 in browser). On the other hand, if I move the coordinates state and Input component to inside Map components, this refreshing is not happening and it just works fine but I was thinking it's not good structure(Input in Map).

Comment: @Md.AbuSayed  I was actually wondering If I use Redux or Context API I would avoid this problem. If I go one of this, I think I would choose Context. Will it help? By the way I didn't understand clearly what you mean by keeping components independent. Do you mean, in this case, having Input inside Map component and this becomes "SearchMap" component?

Comment: @김민겸 Can you include the code for Map in your question please?

Comment: @JamieDixon I edited it. So here, if I move const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({lat:3, lng:2}); into function Map() and also move PlaceSearchInput to return in function Map(), it does work fine without the refreshing issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, I moved Map and WrappedMap's creation out of the of the Search component.
I believe that the change in the component definition every time the component re-rendered likely caused react to think it's an entirely new component and unmount the old and mount the new rather than re-render.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PlaceSearchInput from './PlaceSearchInput';
import { GoogleMap, withGoogleMap } from 'react-google-maps';

function Map({ center }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleMap defaultZoom={10} center={center} />
    </div>
  );
}

const WrappedMap = withGoogleMap(Map);

export default function Search(props) {
  const [mapCenter, setMapCenter] = useState({ lat: 3, lng: 2 });

  if (!props.isGoogleMapApiReady) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  return (
    <div style={{ margin: '100px' }}>
      <div style={{ height: '50vh', width: '50vh' }}>
        <WrappedMap
          loadingElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          containerElement={<div id="map" style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          mapElement={<div style={{ height: '100%' }} />}
          center={mapCenter}
        />
        <PlaceSearchInput setMapCenter={setMapCenter} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```